# Elvis Operator with *ngFor

Tags: angular

is it legal to use Elvis operator with `*ngFor` like this (place question mark after `users`, since that array might be null at the moment)?

```
<tr *ngFor="#user of users?">
  <td> {{user.username}}</td>
</tr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array `users` is null, the Elvis operator in `{{user.username}}` is redundant because the `<td>...</td>` never gets created and `{{user.username}}` isn't evaluated at all.

Comment: i am asking about the Elvis operator inside `<tr>` following `users`, not `<td>`.  are you saying if `users` is null, there is no need for Elvis operator anywhere?

Comment: If `users` is null, there is no need for the Elvis operator. The Elvis operator also doesn't make sense at the end of an expression, only before `.`. If you want to iterate a property of `users` than the Elvis operator makes sense (like `<tr *ngFor="#user of users?.contacts">`)